# ScriptExitException error while creating domain class [grails]

Tags: grails

i am getting 'ScriptExitException' while running this grails app.

the only change in the code is this Domain Class

> class Album {
>
> ```
> static constraints = {
>   String title
>   static hasMany = [songs:Song]
> } }
> ```

console-output:

> grails> run-app | Compiling 1 source files. | Error Compilation error:
>   startup failed:
>   APP-FOLDER/grails-app/domain/com/gtunes/Album.groovy:
>   7: Modifier 'static' not allowed here.  @ line 7, column 6.
>             static hasMany = [songs:Song]
>           ^
>
> 1 error | Error Error running script run-app:
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.ScriptExitException (Use --stacktrace
>   to see the full trace)

I have to keep it static, because it's being used somewhere.. 
any idea what should fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

re arrange your class like this

```
class Album {

      String title
      static hasMany = [songs:Song]


      static constraints = {

      } 

}
```

Comment: Thanks @rami-enbashi.
this change in groovy file did make the app run.
But it's not functioning as required. will keep it posted here if this was the right fix.